# Curl resulting in a potential field

Tags: analysis, vector-analysis

Can we find a vector field $\mathbf{A}$ such that

$\nabla\times\mathbf{A}=q\nabla p$ ,

where $q,p$ scalar functions of the position?

Comment: Are you sure that the double curl is actually changing anything? That is, are you sure that the set of double curls of smooth vector fields is distinct from the set of curls of smooth vector fields? I actually suspect it is not.

Comment: @Ian the double curl changes the outcome.

Comment: Can you give an example of a field that is a curl and is not a double curl?

Comment: @Ian I think you're right! So the proper question would be: Find $A$ such that $\nabla \times \mathbf{A}=q\nabla p$

Answer (score 0):

For arbitrary $p$ and $q$ this equation may not have a solution. Taking the divergence in both sides of the equation we see that a necessary condition for the equation to have a solution is that $\vec\nabla\cdot(q\vec\nabla p)=0$, or equivalently that  $q\vec\nabla p=\vec\nabla\times\vec B$ for some vector field $\vec B$ (function of the position). In that case any solution to $\vec\nabla\times\vec A = \vec B+\vec\nabla\Phi$, with $\Phi$ some scalar field (and there are always solutions to this equation) will solve your equation. One only needs to find $\Phi$ so this equation is compatible, which requires that $\vec\nabla\cdot(\vec\nabla\times \vec A) =\vec\nabla\cdot \vec B + \nabla^2\Phi=0$. Solving this Poisson equation to find $\Phi$ ($\nabla^2\Phi=-\vec\nabla\cdot \vec B$), and inserting in $\vec\nabla\times\vec A = \vec B+\vec\nabla\Phi$ will give a solution of your original problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in general, "***No!***"

For if

$\nabla \times \mathbf A = q \nabla p, \tag 1$

then, since [the divergence of a curl always vanishes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities), (1) implies

$\nabla \cdot (q \nabla p) = \nabla \cdot (\nabla \times \mathbf A) = 0; \tag 2$

also,

$\nabla \cdot (q \nabla p) = \nabla q \cdot \nabla p + q \nabla^2 p; \tag 3$

thus a necessary condition for (1) to hold is that $p$ and $q$ together obey the equation

$q\nabla^2 p + \nabla q \cdot \nabla p = 0, \tag 4$

which is clearly not the case for arbitrary $p$ and $q$.